# Approximating the function $F(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(x) ( x^2 - 1 )}$

Tags: functions, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am interested in the function $F : (1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$
F(x) \ = \ \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{\mathrm{ln}(t)( t^2 - 1 )}
$$

There is of course, no closed-form expression for the above integral and I am only interested in the behaviour of this function for $x \in (1,\infty)$

By goofing around on wolfram alpha, I've found that:

- $f(x)$ seems to have a finite value for all $x \in (1,\infty)$
- $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$
- $f(x) = + \infty$ as $x \to 1^{+}$

Is there a way to understand the asymptotics of this function as $x \to 1^{+}$? Or understanding it's expansion as $x \to \infty$?

I am trying to approximate this function at these two limits, and have never encountered how to deal with approximating functions that are defined as integrals....

Comment: For $x\to\infty$, it will behave as $\int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2 \ln t}$, i.e. asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$. See e.g. [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415425/why-2n-int-infty-n-fraccx2-logx-sim-n-fraccn-logn/2415432#2415432).

Comment: As $t\rightarrow 1^+$, the integrand is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2(t-1)^2}$, so I would expect the integral to be asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2(x-1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\to\infty$, it will behave as $\int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2 \ln t}$, i.e. asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{1}{x\ln x}$. See e.g. [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415425/why-2n-int-infty-n-fraccx2-logx-sim-n-fraccn-logn/2415432#2415432).

For $x\to1^+$, observe that
$$
\frac{1}{(t^2-1)\ln t} = \frac{1}{(t+1)(t-1)\ln(1+ t-1)} \operatorname*{\sim}_{t\to 1^+}\frac{1}{2(t-1)^2}
$$
using the Taylor expansion to first order of $\ln(1+u)$ at $0$. By the same kind of comparison theorems,$^{(\dagger)}$ we thus have
$$
\int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{(t^2-1)\ln t} \operatorname*{\sim}_{x\to 1^+}\int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{2(t-1)^2} = \frac{1}{2(x-1)} 
$$

---

$(\dagger)$ Specifically, here: if $f,g\geq 0$ are locally integrable with $f\sim_0 g$ and the integral of $f$ diverges at $a$, then so does that of $g$, and $\int_x^\infty f \sim_{x\to a}\int_x^\infty g$.